# Randomly pair items in a list using Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a way to randomly pair up students in my class. Here's what I came up with:

```
import random

students = ['Joe', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Jill', 'Paul', 'Eric', 'Chai', 'Chris', 'Sui', 
'Matt', 'Leon', 'Nami', 'Leonard', 'Sai', 'Mike', 'Julie', 'Jim', 'Holly',
'Marge', 'Ed']

random.shuffle(students)

group1 = students[0:10]
group2 = students[10:]

combined = zip(group1, group2)

for first_student, second_student in combined:
    print str(first_student), "and", str(second_student)
```

But how would you do this if you didn't already know the number of students? Any other suggestion on how to improve this?

EDIT: Below is the finished product incorporating several suggestions. I wanted to do this without importing itertools. (Because I want to understand what's going on.)

```
import random

students = ['Joe', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Jill', 'Paul', 'Eric', 'Chai', 'Chris', 'Sui', 
'Matt', 'Leon', 'Nami', 'Leonard', 'Sai', 'Mike', 'Julie', 'Jim', 'Holly',
'Marge', 'Ed']

random.shuffle(students)

groups = zip(*[iter(students)]*2)

for first_student, second_student in groups:
    print str(first_student), "and", str(second_student)
```

Comment: `group1 = students[0:(len(students)//2)]`?

Comment: Why not just shuffle the entire list of students and then break the resulting list into pairs?

Comment: Also, just a little note, you might want to add spaces before and after the `and` when concating the names.

Comment: @1Darco1, that's already added by the `print` statement. Better would be to use a format string.

Comment: @Cyphase, oh right, there are commas not + signs. Silly me.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point. I apparently over-engineered it a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution limits the possible pairings by splitting the students into two groups, and only taking one from each group. It would be better to just do one shuffle on the whole list of students, then take two at a time to make the pairs.

```
import random

from itertools import izip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # Taken from itertools recipes:
    # https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


students = ['Joe', 'Sam', 'Bob', 'Jill', 'Paul', 'Eric', 'Chai', 'Chris',
            'Sui', 'Matt', 'Leon', 'Nami', 'Leonard', 'Sai', 'Mike',
            'Julie', 'Jim', 'Holly', 'Marge', 'Ed']

random.shuffle(students)

for first_student, second_student in grouper(students, 2):
    print str(first_student), "and", str(second_student)
```

Comment: Total unique combinations of two pairs of students is 190. Your object grouper(students, 2) returns only 10.

Comment: @mmachine, it only returns 10 because there are only 10 pairs of students in 20 students. However, every one of the 190 possible pairs is possible in my code, whereas in the OPs original code, only pairs where one student is in `group1` and the other is in `group2` are possible; only 100 out of 190 pairs could ever happen.

Comment: My solution is like putting the students into a big bag, shaking it around, then taking out two a time to make pairs.

Comment: _No students were harmed in the making of this answer_.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used this code to solve it.

```
import random

students_list_1 = ['Hadi', 'Farzad', 'Amirhossein', 'Yasaman']
students_list_2 = students_list_1.copy()

random.shuffle(students_list_1)
random.shuffle(students_list_2)

while len(students_list_2) > 0:
    if students_list_2[-1] == students_list_1[-1]:
        std2 = students_list_2.pop(0)
        std1 = students_list_1.pop()
        print(std1, '-', std2)
        students_list_1.remove(std2)
        students_list_2.remove(std1)
    else:
        std2 = students_list_2.pop()
        std1 = students_list_1.pop()
        print(std1, '-', std2)
        students_list_1.remove(std2)
        students_list_2.remove(std1)
```