# Random Pairing with Odd Array Size

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have an array/list from which I want to randomly form pairs.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296266/randomly-pair-items-in-a-list-using-python) that is perfect, except that if there's an odd number in the array, it matches the oddball to "None."

Is there a way to form a group of three in instances where the array size is odd?
I'm assuming doing some sort of "if/then" using grouper, but I'm not that familiar with grouper.

```
import random

from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


people = ['John','Jacob','Jill','Jane','Josephine']

random.shuffle(people)

for first_person, second_person in grouper(people, 2):
    print(str(first_person), "and", str(second_person))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the grouper function to handle arrays with odd sizes by checking the length of the input iterable and forming groups of three if necessary.
This can be solved in many ways but here is one way I tested.

```
import random
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    if len(iterable) % 2 == 1:
        groups = list(zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue))
        last_group = groups.pop()
        groups[-1] = (groups[-1][0], groups[-1][1], last_group[0])
        return groups
    else:
        return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

people = ['John','Jacob','Jill','Jane','Josephine','Zane']

random.shuffle(people)

for group in grouper(people, 2):
    if len(group) == 3 and group[2] is not None:
        print(str(group[0]), "and", str(group[1]), "and", str(group[2]))
    else:
        print(str(group[0]), "and", str(group[1]))
```

If you need any explanation for this code let me know.

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but I get two random pairs and then a final "pair" with person + "None"as I did in my original.